# Count users redirected from Facebook

Tags: redirect, facebook

I would like to know if there is any way to count the number of users who had been redirected to my wordpress-site by facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a facebook business page and are hoping to track so you can measure the worth of paying them for views.  If so you need to use the facebook tracking pixel and slap the script they give you into your header.

https://www.facebook.com/business/a/facebook-pixel

Comment: If that worked for you then accept the answer for me!